# import * only allowed at module level. Python 3.3 using Pyscripter

Tags: python, pygame, pyscripter

I'm fairly new to programming in general and I just started using python to try and make a simple game using pygame.   If I run the following code in the Python IDLE shell it works fine but if I use Pyscripter I get the error:

```
SyntaxError: import * only allowed at module level
```

I really like using Pyscripter because so far it has made learning the syntax much easier but now I don't understand what is wrong.  Any help would be great. Thanks.

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()
DISPLAYSURF = pygame.display.set_mode((400,300),0,32)
pygame.display.set_caption('Hello World!')
while True: #main game loop
     for event in pygame.event.get():
         if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
     pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: Hrm, I wasn't aware that Pyscripter runs your code in a function. The exception is raised because inside a function you are not allowed to create a variable number of locals (which is what `from modulename import *` does).

Comment: You can 'fix' it by only importing names you are actually using; `from pygame.locals import QUIT` would do here.

Comment: This is weird.  Executing things inside a function instead of at the global level significantly changes the semantics of the code.  The fact that `import *` isn't working is just one of the symptoms.

Comment: Thanks, that worked.  Would you recommend not using Pyscripter then?  Seems like it will get annoying if I have to individual import everything.

Comment: which version of pyscripter are you using? Are you sure your import code is not inside the autogenerated main function?

Comment: O wow, Bartlomiej is right.  What a silly mistake.  Thank you so much.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is when you execute `from pygame.locals import *` you are accessing all from a file, not a module. When you do something like `from pygame import *`, it should work. It is just that you can only use `import *` at the module level

Comment: This seems entirely wrong, as `pygame.locals` is a module, it's a submodule of the `pygame` package. The issue isn't where the import is coming *from*, but where it's being imported *to*.